# reapply offset values when changing elements dimensions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reapply offset of elements, when their dimensions changed, its working when resizing window. Press + or - to change width of elements - http://jsfiddle.net/srfy5qs4/1/

```
var leg = document.getElementsByClassName('leg');
var num = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
var inc = document.getElementById('inc');

inc.addEventListener('click', expand);
window.addEventListener('resize', render);

function expand(){
    for(var i=0; i<=leg.length; i++){
      leg[i].style.width = 100+"px";
    }
    render();
};

function render(){
  for(var i=0; i<=leg.length; i++){
      num[i].style.left = leg[i].offsetLeft+"px";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `i<=leg.length` to `i<leg.length` in both the `expand` and `render` functions. Arrays start from zero. If you perform a `for` loop that goes until `i==leg.length`, that'll go to `5`-- `leg[5]` and `num[5]` don't exist. It's causing your code to error out before `render()` will be called in the `expand()` function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: damn it =c how couldnt i notice that mistake, thank you